# Why "Cyclic reference" when throwing an exception in Java8 Stream's map function?

Tags: functional-programming, java-8

Basically, the following code won't pass the compiler since the `x -> Optional.of(x).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("")` part is marked as **Cyclic reference**. Can someone tell me why there is a cyclic reference? and what's gonna be the workaround?

`Arrays.asList("a", "b").stream().map(x -> Optional.of(x).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("")));`

Comment: That's not the error I get when I try it. The first error I get is a missing parenthesis, and after fixing that, I get an unhandled exception error. (Also, using `orElseThrow` on the result of `Optional.of` is kind of weird, since `Optional.of` will never return an Optional without a present value.)

Comment: I fixed the missing parenthesis error in the question; thank you for pointing it out. The Exception should be in the method signature to avoid ``` unhandled exception```. Right, the above code make less sense, I just want it to show an example to trigger the ```Cyclic reference``` error.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out: The function inside of `map` can NOT throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

`RuntimeException` works fine in this case:

```
Arrays.asList("a", "b")
        .stream()
        .map(x -> Optional.of(x).orElseThrow(
                () -> new RuntimeException("")));
```